# Why don't my knockout options bindings work?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout to bind dropdowns to an observableArray for the options list.  As far as I can tell, I have followed the examples I've found, but it is not working.  Below are the relevant parts of my code.  This is in a cshtml file in an MVC app, so you'll see some Razor syntax in there.

```
$(function () {
  var $thisdd = $("#@ddname");  //the JQuery selector for my dropdown
  var dropdownItems = new ko.observableArray();

  dropdownItems = getDropdownItemsFromDl("@ddname");

  var newitem = ko.observable({ cname: ddcname, cvalue: ko.observable($thisdd.val()), cpublishtopic: "" });
  classificationsViewModel.push(newitem());
  $thisdd.attr("data-bind", "options: dropdownItems, optionsText: function(item) { return item.value; }, optionsValue: function(item) { return item.key; }, value: classificationsViewModel()[" + classificationsViewModel.indexOf(newitem()) + "].cvalue ");
  ko.applyBindings(newitem);
});
```

After the call to getDropdownItemsFromDl, dropdownItems looks like this in the Chrome debug watch window:

```
dropdownItems(): Array[14]
0: Object
key: "0"
value: "none"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
key: "1"
value: "Equity Portfolio"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
key: "2"
value: "Fixed Income Portfolio"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
length: 14
__proto__: Array[0]
```

classificationsViewModel is a ko.observableArray.  cvalue is a ko.observeable property of objects in that array.

The dropdown options list ends up with only "None", the first item in the array.
What is wrong with my binding attribute?

Comment: Before diving into this, did you call ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, element ) anywhere? I don't see it. This call will bind your viewmodel to your DOM;

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the omission, muck41.  Yes, that line was already in my code and I've updated the posting.

Comment: I think you can't use a function for the `optionsValue` binding. It needs to be a string with the name of the property (e.g. 'key'). In most cases using optionsValue is not the way to go, as you want the values to be maintained by KO

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work **AS LONG AS** the binding to the value is the last script line.  Any javascript after that ko.applyBinding line will not be executed!  I will be creating another question to address that wierdness as this is a serious problem for my app.

Notice that I ended up using a viewModel.  I could not get binding directly to the observableArray to work.

Also note that value: preceeds the options: in the data-bind attribute.  When I had value: as the last part of the attribute, the options bind did not work.

Here are the relevant lines of my code that "work".

```
$(function () {   
  var $thisdd = $("#@ddname");  //the JQuery selector for my dropdown   

  var dropdownItems = getDropdownItemsFromDl("@ddname");    
  var newitem = ko.observable({ cname: ddcname, cvalue: ko.observable($thisdd.val()), cpublishtopic: "" });   
  classificationsViewModel.push(newitem());   

  var viewModel =
    {
        dditems : dropdownItems 
    };

  $("#@ddname").attr("data-bind", "value: classificationsViewModel()[" + classificationsViewModel.indexOf(newitem()) + "].cvalue, options: dditems, optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'key'");
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  ko.applyBindings(classificationsViewModel()[classificationsViewModel.indexOf((newitem())].cvalue);
});
```

I hope that this "answer" helps someone else struggling with this issue.